# expected primary-expression before ';' token

Tags: c++

I am trying to implemented exception and throw it out of my method.

Here is the `h` file for exception

```
#ifndef EXCEPTION_H
#define EXCEPTION_H

#include <exception>
#include <string>

namespace core {

class no_implementation: public std::exception {
private:
    std::string error_message;
public:
    no_implementation(std::string error_message);
    const char* what() const noexcept;
};

typedef no_implementation noimp;

}

#endif
```

And here `cpp` file

```
#include "../headers/exception.h"

using namespace core;

no_implementation::no_implementation(std::string error_message = "Not implemented!") {
    this->error_message = error_message;
}

const char* no_implementation::what() const noexcept {
    return this->error_message.c_str();
}
```

And here is the method

```
std::string IndexedObject::to_string() {
    throw noimp;
}
```

But it shows me error

```
throw noimp; //expected primary-expression before ';' token
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Should that be `throw no_implementation`? Ps use `const` and references when passing `std::String`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a temporary of a type you'll need to use a notation like this (note the extra parenthesis):

```
throw noimp();
```

Without the parenthesis you try to throw a type rather than an object. You'll also specify the string unless you move the default into the declaration: the default needs to be visible when it is being used.

Answer (score 2):

First off, default arguments such as `std::string error_message = "Not implemented!"` should go in the function declaration, not definition. That is, write

```
...
public:
    no_implementation(std::string error_message = "Not implemented!");
...
```

Second, you throw values, not types. You've written `throw noimp;` but `noimp` is the name of a class. This should probably be `throw noimp();` or `throw noimp("some message here");`.